# Change in drop-down updates textbox in same dynamically created row

Tags: jquery, bind

You were so very helpful this morning, that I thought it would be a good bet I could get help on this. I have dynamically created rows in a table, one field is a drop-down to select a fee type. When this is changed I want to update a field in the same row with the $$ amount. I'm getting the correct fee and the correct id from my alerts ("the fee is class_fee[37] and the amount is 225.00"), but the textbox with the fee $$ is not updating.
The the textbox id is  `id="class_fee[<?php echo $i ?>]"` 
 Here is the jQuery (maybe I'm all wrong in how I'm identifying that $$ box?):

```
    $(".fee_id_select").bind("change",function ()
{  
        var $class_fee = 'class_fee[' + this.id + ']';

      jQuery.getJSON(
          'get_fee_json.php',
          {'id': this.value},
          update_fee_amount
      );
        function update_fee_amount(data, textStatus)
        {
            var fee = data || {}; 
      alert('the fee is ' + $class_fee + ' and the amount is ' + fee.fee_amount);                   
            jQuery('#' + $class_fee).val(fee.fee_amount || '');    
        }                                   
});
```

Here is the actual HTML inside a foreach loop:

```
            <td>
                <input type="text" 
                name="students[<?php echo $i ?>][class_fee]" 
                id="class_fee[<?php echo $i ?>]"
                value="<?= html($class['class_fee']) ?>" 
                size="6" >
            </td>
```

(yes, there are brackets. $i is the unique id number from a class registration table.)

Here is a jSon response:

```
{"fee_amount":"25.00"}
```

These all look like great answers, and I've tried them all, but the textbox for the fee amount is not changing. I don't have any errors in Firebug. I'm puzzled.

Comment: Give us a sample JSON response

Answer (score 1):

Because the element is injected into the DOM tree after document load you can't use `.bind()`. You should use `.live()` or better than that `.delegate()`

```
   $(".fee_id_select").live("change",function ()
{  
        var $class_fee = 'class_fee[' + this.id + ']';

      jQuery.getJSON(
          'get_fee_json.php',
          {'id': this.value},
          update_fee_amount
      );
        function update_fee_amount(data, textStatus)
        {
            var fee = data || {}; 
      alert('the fee is ' + $class_fee + ' and the amount is ' + fee.fee_amount);                   
            jQuery('#' + $class_fee).val(fee.fee_amount || '');    
        }                                   
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/live/

http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: Oh... I didn't know that the term `dynamically` was referring to `JavaScript` and not `PHP`

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, `$class_fee` contains `class_fee[37]`, whereas the id you want (probably) is `class_fee37`.

Something like this should work, I think

```
jQuery('#class_fee' + this.id).val(fee.fee_amount || '');
```

If it doesn't, please post the HTML for the textbox.

Comment: The OP did provide the id for the textbox: _The textbox id is id="class_fee[<?php echo $i ?>]"_

Comment: @Rolando Which is presumably `class_fee37`, which I included in my answer. There's nothing written in concrete that says "A variable called `$i` must only be numeric" though, so if this code doesn't work, the odds are good that the ID I assumed to be correct is wrong :)

Comment: I am sorry if I cannot see where you are coming from. The OP explicitly said that the markup expects an ID in this format `class_fee[id]`. That is why we do not need to presume that the **format** of `$class_fee` is wrong. `$i` is probably from a `for` or `while` loop declared like this `$i = 0; ... $i++;` that is why I assumed that `$i` will always be numeric. But I think we both share the same guess that the value of `this.id` in `$class_fee` is wrong. Please correct me if I am wrong. =)

Comment: Ah, I missed the bit where he said the ID of the textbox had [ ] around it - seen it now :) You win :P

Comment: I've looked and looked. the source for the page is                 <td>
                    <input type="text" 
                    name="students[37][class_fee]" 
                    id="class_fee[37]"
                    value="175.00" 
                    size="6" >
                </td>  and the alert returns: class fee is class_fee[37] and the amount is 25.00